# phpMyAdmin FK Constraints difference action when I delete each table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

My problem I want add 2 actions when I delete from Each table

Example : 
Table(A) Relationship to column Token in Table(B).
When I delete data in Table(A) action will be (CASCADE) delete data in Table(B) same
But I delete data in Table(B) action will be (SET NULL) in Table(A).

My table(user authentication) has token column  reference to FK(token) in table(token)
[image]

I add action constraint SET_NULL.
It action SET NULL when I delete data in Table(token)

But if I delete data in Table(user authentication)
I want to delete data in Table(token) too
[image]

Comment: Remove photos and post full CREATE TABLE scripts (and maybe INSERT INTO scripts with sample data). Show/describe the action and desired result (tables content).

Comment: *When I delete data in Table(A) action will be (CASCADE) delete data in Table(B) same
But I delete data in Table(B) action will be (SET NULL) in Table(A).* The relation is oriented - so only uni-directional action may exist.

Comment: ok I understand it just only unidirectional action if I want to action each table I have to code for remove it

Comment: No. Action for change on the "many" side makes no sense. Imagine that one "one" row has two "many" rows. You delete one "many" row - and you want to delete "one" row too??? Second "many" row will be very glad to you...

Comment: Ok Thank , I got it